# Adventure Of A Lifetime — is this an animated video clip?

Tags: music-video

I watched Coldplay's [Adventure Of A Lifetime](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QtXby3twMmI) many times, yet was not able to decide whether it's animated, using some sort of "dummies", or combination.

Can anyone tell the secret of those gorillas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should see this one : [Adventure of A Lifetime : Behind The Scenes](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GnPfDX4mZ40). It confirms that they use motion capture technology.

[image: coldplay]

They have captor suits and move like apes.

[image: coldplay]

Answer (score 3):

It was done using motion capture. [According to Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adventure_of_a_Lifetime#Music_video), emphasis mine:

> The official music video was directed by the band's long-time collaborator, Mat Whitecross. It was released on 27 November 2015. **The concept for the video was hatched after Coldplay frontman Chris Martin and British motion capture expert/actor Andy Serkis met on a plane and discussed ideas.** It took about six months in the making of the music video.

If you've never heard of Andy Serkis, he's done motion capture as Smeagol/Gollum in the *Lord of the Rings*/*Hobbit* film series and as Caesar, an intelligent chimpanzee who is able to talk, in the rebooted *Planet of the Apes* film series.

It also appears that the four chimpanzees in the video were played by the members of Coldplay. Again, [from Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adventure_of_a_Lifetime#Synopsis):

> As it opens, four chimpanzees (played by the band members) are sitting in a forest.